# Add Square brackets to the end of JSON in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Below is an of my JSON which is logged after subscribe.

```
{
   "serviceList": [
    {
      "serviceId": 1486366732440,
      "sourceId": 5231,
    }]
}
```

Is there any way to convert it into,

```
[{
       "serviceList": [
        {
          "serviceId": 1486366732440,
          "sourceId": 5231,
        }]
    }]
```

Comment: Just place your object into an array. It should be that simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {
   "serviceList": [
    {
      "serviceId": 1486366732440,
      "sourceId": 5231,
    }]
};

var new_obj = [obj];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to push into an array, simple like this -

```
const a = {
   "serviceList": [
    {
      "serviceId": 1486366732440,
      "sourceId": 5231,
    }]
}

let b = [];
b.push(a);

console.log(b)
```

Comment: Oh God, that's lame. Sorry and Thank you

Comment: I am able to get the json in [], but with " " from start to end. Is there any solution

Comment: @PavanSista what do you mean by `with ""`? this is not valid JSON

Comment: The output I am getting is [ "{some Json data}" ]. I don't understand why. Maybe there is something that needs to be done with the HttpClient.post().

Comment: But this is weird response `[ "{some Json data}" ]` , you must need to change something, can you reproduce the same error on stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

just push it inside an array for example:

```
   var a = {
   "serviceList": [
    {
      "serviceId": 1486366732440,
      "sourceId": 5231,
    }]
   }

var b=[];
b.push(a);
```